# Counting results of a call to the database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have run this in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT user_id, DATE(comment_date) comment_date, 
       COUNT(*) comment_ID 
FROM wp_comments  
WHERE user_id='3' 
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(comment_date) ;
```

and shows me 4 results, but when this other sim in PHP, sample 3 results:

```
global $current_user, $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_id, DATE(comment_date) comment_date, 
                         COUNT(*) comment_ID FROM ".$wpdb->comments.
                       " WHERE user_id='".$current_user->ID."'
                       GROUP BY user_id, DATE(comment_date) ;");
echo $count;
```

When you run the query in PHP:

```
echo "SELECT user_id, DATE(comment_date) comment_date, COUNT(*) comment_ID
FROM ".$wpdb->comments." 
WHERE user_id='".$current_user->ID."'
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(comment_date) ;";
```

Displays:

SELECT user_id, DATE(comment_date) comment_date, COUNT(*) comment_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE user_id='3' GROUP BY user_id, DATE(comment_date) ;

Comment: `echo` the $current_user->id and verify the query is using the one you think it is

Comment: I'd actually echo the entire SQL command just to be sure your comments variable is correct as well.

Comment: yes, $current_user->ID is 3 and $wpdb->comments is wp_comments. I checked... I've even tried with another user and does not give the expected result.

Comment: Do you mean it shows 4 rows and then 3 rows or 4 columns and then 3 columns???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you are sure, the userId is 3?

Update:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var()
```

returns the first parameter of the sql query. this is in your query the user_id which is 3.

you have to use

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results()
```

then there should be an array of results.

Comment: yes, $current_user->ID is 3 and $wpdb->comments is wp_comments. I checked... I've even tried with another user and does not give the expected result.

Comment: ah, i got the error.

        `$wpdb->get_var()`

returns the first parameter of the sql query.

this is in your query the user_id which is 3.

you have to use `$wpdb->get_results()` this returns an array.